# SQL SELECT JOIN and DB Architecture

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

As I cannot mange to build a join for getting expected results I started thinking the whole architecture may be wrong.

Models (relevant fields only):

```
public class AspNetUsers // this is ASPNET default identity table modified
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int GeoID { get; set; } // FK to GeoData PK
        public string Email { get; set; }

public partial class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; } // FK to Category PK
        public string UserID { get; set; } // FK to AspNetUsers PK

 public partial class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

 public class GeoData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DbGeography GeoLocation { get; set; }

public class WishList
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string userEmail { get; set; } // FK to AspnetUsers 'Email'
        public int frequency { get; set; }
        public int category { get; set; } // FK to Category PK
        public int range { get; set; }
        public int geoid { get; set; } // FK to Geodata PK
```

The idea is: we have products and categories. Products are user's related. The userID FK in Products model accounts for that, linking each Product to its owner in the AspNetUsers table as every User registers, logs in ecc... through aspnet identity.
Before setting their products Users must geolocate themself so that their products can be conveniently geolocated (searched) by other users.
The Geodata table accounts for worldwide coordinates, postal codes, placenames ecc..
Now to the WishList. Every user may set up to 'n' wishlists setting a category they're interested in, plus a location and a range from that location. 
Whislists' result is being emailed by sql server to users, scheduled upon 'frequency' field.

I am not sure this is the best possible db architecture. Sometimes you just start with some building blocks (AspNetUsers, Products, Categories), adding other functionality time by time.
Anyway.. here's a basic SELECT to build the emails to be sent depending on users' different wishlists:

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [userEmail], [frequency], [category],[range], w.[geoid], [searchCity], u.UserName, g.[GeoLocation]
FROM WishLists as w
JOIN AspNetUsers as u ON w.userEmail = u.Email
JOIN GeoData_IT as g ON g.ID = w.geoid

OPEN C1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
    @userEmail, @frequency, @category, @range, @geoid, @searchCity, @userName, @GeoLocation
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    IF @geoid > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT p.ID, c.Name, p.Name, g.PlaceName
                          FROM WishLists as w
                          RIGHT OUTER JOIN GeoData_IT AS g ON w.geoid = g.ID
                          JOIN AspNetUsers AS u ON g.ID = u.GeoID
                          JOIN Products as p on u.Id = p.UserID
                          JOIN Categories AS c ON p.CategoryID = c.ID
                          WHERE g.GeoLocation.STDistance(@GeoLocation) <= (@range*5000)

            END
            FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
            @userEmail, @frequency, @category, @range, @geoid, @searchCity, @userName, @GeoLocation
    END

CLOSE C1;
DEALLOCATE C1;
GO
```

I am not even introducing the 'category' complication at this point, just checking whether wishlist contains a relevant geoid (if geoid >0) trying to extract, for each wishlist, any product belonging to users whose geolocation is in the given range from the given geoid.
Yet I am getting some duplicated result, randomly on certain wishlist only, and I cannot figure out why.

This looks fine:

```
1   Nursery Loved Crib Bale Genoa
2   Baby products   Crib    Genoa
3   Baby products   Cot Bed Genoa
4   Feeding Circus Crib Bale    Genoa
```

While this shows duplicates:

```
1555    Baby products   this  uaga product  Recco
1555    Baby products   this  uaga product  Recco
1556    Automotive  uaga product    Recco
1556    Automotive  uaga product    Recco
```

Is the entire architecture failing or just the SELECT?

Comment: There are several problems with your data model including why a wishlist has a geoid and why does it have the userEmail instead of userId? Also Products shouldn't have a UserId; the wishlist should have the ProductId. As far as the select and why you have duplicates? It could be that 2 wishlists for two different users have the same geoid and then you would see two rows like your results.

Comment: 1. As userEmail is unique in AspNetUsers table it can be used as a PK thus eliminating the need to involve JOIN in many circumstances. 2. There's a one to many relation between userid and products. Sure I could complicate the architecture using a 3rd table: would this be strongly advisable ? 3. A wishlist has nothing to do with single products. A wishlist targets a location, a range from that location and eventually a category. Sure in case users ask for two or twenty identical wishlists (not very wise indeed), asking for same place, range distance and category they will get identical results.

Comment: I realized after my comment that wishlist was location based; I can also ignore the userEmail in the wishlist. About (3) in your comment, the problem is not if users request identical wishlists, the problem is if two different users have a wishlist for the same geoid, both users will get duplicate rows by your select statement ```FROM WishLists as w RIGHT OUTER JOIN GeoData_IT AS g ON w.geoid = g.ID JOIN AspNetUsers AS u ON g.ID = u.GeoID``` because you are missing the join on the Email. Apart from this, the relationship between user and product doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I also don't have any idea why you would be using a right outer join - if users don't have a wishlist, send them an empty email anyway? Are users both owners of products via the UserID on products and consumers of products via wishlist - category - product? That kinda makes sense but is not straightforward from the schema. Also if you are only going to use the geoid, GeoLocation and range variables in the cursor (ugh), I wouldn't load the other variables. Overall I would say yes your architecture needs help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the architecture, the problem being the SELECT not referencing WishLists ID on fetching. Here is the corrected code:

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT w.ID, w.userEmail, w.category, w.range, w.geoid, w.searchCity, u.UserName, g.GeoLocation
FROM WishLists as w JOIN AspNetUsers as u ON w.userEmail = u.Email JOIN GeoData_IT as g ON g.ID = w.geoid
WHERE w.frequency = 1 order by w.ID
OPEN C1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
    @WishListID, @userEmail, @category, @range, @geoid, @searchCity, @userName, @GeoLocation
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    if @geoid > 0
            begin
        if @category > 0
                begin
            SELECT p.ID, c.Name, p.Name, g.PlaceName
                          FROM Products as p 
                          JOIN Categories AS c ON p.CategoryID = c.ID
                          JOIN AspNetUsers AS u ON p.UserID = u.Id
                          JOIN WishLists AS w ON @WishListID = w.ID
                          JOIN GeoData_IT AS g ON u.GeoID = g.ID
                          WHERE p.IsApproved = 1 AND p.IsDeleted = 0 AND p.DateExpire > convert(date, getdate()) 
                          AND w.IsDeleted = 0 AND g.GeoLocation.STDistance(@GeoLocation) <= (@range*5000)
                          AND p.CategoryID = @category
                          order by p.ID
                    end -- category != 0 
            end -- @geoid > 0 
            FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
            @WishListID, @userEmail, @category, @range, @geoid, @searchCity, @userName, @GeoLocation

      END

CLOSE C1;
DEALLOCATE C1;
```

the key line being

`JOIN WishLists AS w ON @WishListID = w.ID`

Comment: That SQL is significantly different from the original (including getting rid of the right outer join). Also, how are you connecting the users to the wishlists again? This select is still wrong and problematic. And **no**, your architecture still has significant problems.

Comment: Thanks buddy I just would like to express my gratitude. I couldn't have made it without all of your technical suggestions. It's really hard to say which one of your posts was the more useful, all of them telling so much about your will for helping other users of this community from the heights of the deep experience and knowledge you've been so kind to share. You're the best!

Comment: You are welcome; I do this in my downtime and I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use stored procedures or cursors (cursors are to avoid whenever possible, try to use different techniques such as CTEs), then you should definitely go database first. There is no benefits for you to use the code first approach.

That said, you are apparently not declaring relationships between tables using  ICollection.

Furthermore, you are not using data annotations to determine primary keys using [KEY] or limiting the size of your string columns using [MAXLENGTH(n)]. Your tables are without primary and foreign keys and all string columns are NVARCHAR(MAX) as a result. Your tables are going to take a lot of room as a result.

What you are getting is a Cartesian product and it is expected. If you want to avoid it without looking deep into the logic of your query, use DISTINCT or GROUP BY.

Comment: The 'partial' declaration should suggest you other partial classes are being used for defining metadada. Nevertheless, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, there are two partial classes, but without the rest of the implementation code, we can't really help you either. 

As is, this post sounds more like a "do my job for me" than a reasonable theoretical question.